# How do I fix Perl's Font::FreeType compilation errors?

Tags: perl, compiler-errors, cpan, freetype

I am trying to install the Perl module [Font::FreeType](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Font-FreeType) on a CentOS linux box using cpan. I run `sudo cpan` and inside the cpan shell I run `install Font::FreeType`. However `make` fails as follows:

```
Writing Makefile for Font::FreeType
cp lib/Font/FreeType.pm blib/lib/Font/FreeType.pm
cp lib/Font/FreeType/Face.pm blib/lib/Font/FreeType/Face.pm
cp lib/Font/FreeType/Glyph.pm blib/lib/Font/FreeType/Glyph.pm
/usr/bin/perl /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8/ExtUtils/xsubpp  -typemap /usr/lib/perl5/5.8.8/ExtUtils/typemap -typemap typemap  FreeType.xs > FreeType.xsc && mv FreeType.xsc FreeType.c
gcc -c  -I/usr/include/freetype2 -D_REENTRANT -D_GNU_SOURCE -fno-strict-aliasing -pipe -Wdeclaration-after-statement -I/usr/local/include -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -I/usr/include/gdbm -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m32 -march=i386 -mtune=generic -fasynchronous-unwind-tables   -DVERSION=\"0.03\" -DXS_VERSION=\"0.03\" -fPIC "-I/usr/lib/perl5/5.8.8/i386-linux-thread-multi/CORE"   FreeType.c
FreeType.c: In function ‘XS_Font__FreeType_new’:
FreeType.c:425: warning: unused variable ‘class’
FreeType.xs: In function ‘XS_Font__FreeType__Face_has_reliable_glyph_names’:
FreeType.xs:528: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘FT_Has_PS_Glyph_Names’
FreeType.xs: In function ‘XS_Font__FreeType__Glyph_char_code’:
FreeType.xs:808: error: invalid lvalue in assignment
```

I have googled but can't seem to find any advice on how to solve this issue. I have a feeling something may be corupted with cpane, because when I went to check my version, I was surprised:

```
# sudo cpan --version
/usr/bin/cpan version [unknown] calling Getopt::Std::getopts (version 1.05 [paranoid]),
running under Perl version 5.8.8.
```

Comment: From the command line, you should be able to just run `cpan Font::FreeType`. That doesn't solve your problem. You should only need sudo for the install step, so you can configure CPAN.pm to use that. I'm curious what your cpan source looks like since I don't support a --version switch. :)

Comment: @brian d foy: Thanks for the tips and for cleaning up my title! Apparently my cpan doesn't really support a version switch either ;-) It's Centos 5.4 if that matters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See http://rt.cpan.org/Public/Dist/Display.html?Name=Font-FreeType, the RT queue has patches you can apply to make the module build correctly.

Ether and Cfreak were guessing wrong, it's simply a bug due to bitrot in `Font::FreeType`.

Comment: That was exactly what I was googling for and couldn't find for some reason. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you don't have the freetype development package installed. On the command line try:

```
yum install freetype-devel
```

Let that install and then rerun the install for your perl module. (you man need to do clean Font::Freetype first)

Comment: Hmmm, just tried that, got `Package freetype-devel-2.2.1-21.el5_3.i386 already installed and latest version`

Answer (score 0):

You can always reinstall cpan either by using itself (`sudo cpan CPAN`), or by manually downloading the CPAN distribution and following the build instructions.

However, generally when you get C-ish compile errors from a CPAN installation, that suggests you might be missing an underlying library. Font::FreeType uses the FreeType2 library; did you install that first? (Is it in /usr/lib/?)

Comment: Yeah, the library is in /usr/lib/...
`lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 21 Jan 20 12:46 /usr/lib/libfreetype.so -> libfreetype.so.6.3.10` -- What's weird is the error is "invalid lvalue in assignment", that sounds to me like an error in the FreeType code, am I incorrect?

Comment: @Josh: yes, or some sort of incompatibility between the FreeType library, the version of the XS layer you downloaded, and Perl itself. This probably warrants contacting the Font::FreeType author directly (or filing a bug report via rt.cpan.org against the module).