# Desperately in need of help compiling Font::FreeType CPAN module with Strawberry Perl

Tags: perl

For literally days now, I have been scouring the web, and cursing and tearing my hair out, trying to compile [Font::FreeType](http://search.cpan.org/~geoffr/Font-FreeType-0.03/lib/Font/FreeType.pm) with **dmake** for *dwimperl-5.14.2.1-v7-32bit* (Strawberry Perl 5.14.2.1). For openers, there are several bugs in the **FreeType.xs** file for which I found a patch at [Bug #32713 for Font-FreeType: patch for Font-FreeType-0.03](https://rt.cpan.org/Public/Bug/Display.html?id=32713). Lovely. The last update for this module is 11 Sep 2004 (note the day) so it is dead for sure, but I need it for using REAL fonts with perlcairo. So I am determined (desperate) to get it working. So far I have had no problems using cpan with the exception of this module. In fact **Strawberry Perl** is the only Windows perl I have used that actually works right out of the box with CPAN. This is obviously a rogue module. Even *nix users have had problems with it.

I read [How do I fix Perl's Font::FreeType compilation errors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2104569/how-do-i-fix-perls-fontfreetype-compilation-errors) but no help there so I think a new thread is justified.

```
Number found where operator expected at Makefile.PL line 17, near "my $font_filename = catfile($data_dir, '5"
  (Might be a runaway multi-line '' string starting on line 9)
    (Do you need to predeclare my?)
```

Makefile.pl:

```perl
1  use ExtUtils::MakeMaker;
2  use File::Spec::Functions;
3  
4  WriteMakefile(
5      NAME            => 'Font::FreeType',
6      AUTHOR          => 'Geoff Richards <qef@laxan.com>',
7      VERSION_FROM    => 'lib/Font/FreeType.pm',
8      LIBS            => [ '-lfreetype' ],
9      INC             => '-I/usr/include/freetype2',
10     NO_META         => 1,
11 );
12 
13 
14 # Generate a listing of the characters in the BDF test font, for checking
15 # that the library can find them all.  See t/10metrics_5x7bdf.t
16 my $data_dir = catdir(qw( t data ));
17 my $font_filename = catfile($data_dir, '5x7.bdf');
```

This runs just fine using perl so what is dmake's problem? If I just run it with perl, **dmake** will re-run it. I can't figure out how to get **dmake** to just use what's there and I find no REAL documenation on **dmake**, just the useless help and man page (at least useless to me).

I tried adding a trailing slash to **$data_dir** but same error. Finally I just set **$font_filename** to the complete path. Crude, I know, but it works.

So this now creates **FreeType.c** but now there are path problems:

```
gcc -c  -I/usr/include/freetype2    -s -O2 -DWIN32 -DPERL_TEXTMODE_SCRIPTS -DUSE_SITECUSTOMIZE -DPERL_IMPLICIT_CONTEXT -DPERL_IMPLICIT_SYS -fno-strict-aliasing -mms-bitfields -s -O2     -DVERSION=\"0.03\"    -DXS_VERSION=\"0.03\"  "-IC:\Dwimperl\perl\lib\CORE"   FreeType.c
FreeType.xs:19:22: fatal error: ft2build.h: No such file or directory
```

FreeType.c contains:

```c
#include <ft2build.h>
#include FT_FREETYPE_H
```

I tried changing include paths in *Makefile.pl* but I really don't know the "proper" way to do that:

```perl
WriteMakefile(
    .
    LIBS            => '-LC:/gtk/lib -lfreetype',
    INC             => '-IC:/gtk/include/freetype2 -IC:/gtk/include -IC:/Dwimperl/c/include',
```

I think now the problem is converting *nix paths to Windows ones so the compiler can find all the header files. Has anyone successfully compiled this damned module in Windows using ANY compiler? Or does anyone at least know how to specify the Windows paths for *WriteMakefile*?

Comment: Beyond a personal vendetta, why do you need Font::FreeType? What is your goal?

Comment: It sounds like you have got beyond it, but there is no way that `dmake` should be running `Makefile.PL`. Running that Perl file creates the `Makefile` that `dmake` should be executing.

Comment: @ titanofold 
Is this a trick question or a PERSONAL attack?
What part of *"I need it for using REAL fonts with perlcairo"* 
DON'T you understand? Are you trying to help me or are you yet another troll?

Comment: @ Borodin  
  
Yeah, you're right. It was so far back that I did that part, I forgot exactly how that error occurred. But it did so after I modified the **INC             =>** statement to change the include directory. I tried it just now and perl had no problem with it. And dmake used the resulting Makefile. So maybe **cpan** did it. In any case, the path problem still remains. I need to know how to change it so it works.

Answer (score 1):

I was also trying to get the latest FreeType module to install on cygwin using cpan like so:

```
$ cpan

cpan shell -- CPAN exploration and modules installation (v1.9800)
Enter 'h' for help.

cpan[1]> install Font::FreeType
```

The first issue I ran into was during the make phase.  Make was complaining about not being able to find ft2build.h.

It's then that I realized I had to download and compile/install the FreeType library first (doh!).  So, I downloaded the latest from the FreeType [download](http://download.savannah.gnu.org/releases/freetype/) page, and installed it like so:

```
$ cd cygwin/freetype-2.4.0
$ ./configure
...
$ make
...
$ make install
```

The next issue is that when I tried to make the module in cpan again, it was failing at the following line in ft2build.h:

```
#include <freetype/config/ftheader.h>
```

If you take a look at the actual file (in /usr/local/include/ft2build.h on my system, but it may be somewhere else on yours) you will see this comment before that line:

```
/* `<prefix>/include/freetype2' must be in your current inclusion path */
```

So, I set the appropriate environment variable (The "proper" way, I believe -- better than modifying the "INC" line in the make file):

```
$ C_INCLUDE_PATH=/usr/local/include/freetype2
$ export C_INCLUDE_PATH
```

After fixing that, the next problem I ran into is the lvalue error:

```
$ cpan install Font::FreeType
CPAN: Storable loaded ok (v2.27)
...
FreeType.xs:808:21: error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment
...
Makefile:340: recipe for target `FreeType.o' failed
make: *** [FreeType.o] Error 1
  GEOFFR/Font-FreeType-0.03.tar.gz
  /usr/bin/make -- NOT OK
CPAN: YAML loaded ok (v0.84)
Running make test
  Can't test without successful make
Running make install
  Make had returned bad status, install seems impossible
```

I know you've already fixed that, but I'll post the info here in case someone else runs into it.  Save the patch file from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2104569/how-do-i-fix-perls-fontfreetype-compilation-errors) to FreeType.xs.diff (Your Font-FreeType-0.03 directory may be named differently), apply it, and make/compile like below.  Note that since we modified the module we can't use cpan anymore, thus we make it manually:

```
$ cd ~/.cpan/build/Font-FreeType-0.03
$ patch FreeType.xs FreeType.xs.diff
patching file FreeType.xs

$ make
Makefile out-of-date with respect to Makefile.PL
...
==> Your Makefile has been rebuilt. <==
==> Please rerun the make command.  <==
false
Makefile:866: recipe for target `Makefile' failed
make: *** [Makefile] Error 1

$ make
cp lib/Font/FreeType.pm blib/lib/Font/FreeType.pm
...
Manifying blib/man3/Font.FreeType.3pm

$ make install
Files found in blib/arch: installing files in blib/lib into architecture dependent library tree
...
Appending installation info to /usr/lib/perl5/5.14/i686-cygwin-threads-64int/perllocal.pod
```

Voila!  It's compiled!  Another thing to point out is that I used regular gnu make rather than dmake, as Borodin pointed out earlier.  The FreeType install notes say you have to run GNU Make 3.80 or later.  You can check what version of make you have installed like this:

```
$ make -v
GNU Make 3.82.90
Built for i686-pc-cygwin
Copyright (C) 2010  Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response. This is the best one so far. I am using dwimperl which comes with dmake and the mingw compiler installed. I also have the freetype binaries via gtk+ 2. I don't know if nmake would make much of a difference but I don't think it is compatible: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9799584/comparison-of-make-and-nmake-for-perl-module-installation.

Comment: I could also try to install freetype separately like you did. I am assuming it sets the correct path to its libraries. But the path would have to be a windows path since I am not in a unix environment like in cygwin.